# Emailed invoice PDF line items missing

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, invoice, system-workflow-messages

I have setup a webform to process membership renewals via a checksum. When the user pays they are sent a pdf invoice which is missing information such as description, quantity and unit price (see attached screen capture).

However, the correct PDF invoice is sent when I select the following: 
Home » CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Manage Contribution Pages » Receipt » Tick Email Receipt to Contributor?

The issue with this is that Civi will also send the email with the missing information.

Does anyone know how I can get the correct information to display on the first email? Or to stop 2 emails being sent when: Email Receipt to Contributor - is selected?

All message templated are default. CiviCRM 5.26.1. Drupal 7.71

Edit: Second screen capture of desired outcome.

[image: missing information]
[image: Ticked: Email Receipt to Contributor?]

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the screenshot of the webform used to retrieve membership renewals? Not sure what you expect in the description, qty field.

> Or to stop 2 emails being sent when: Email Receipt to Contributor - is selected?

Check whether `Automatically email invoice when user purchases online` is enabled on contribution settings? - `Administer => CiviContribute => CiviContribute Component Settings`

[image]

Comment: The webform is quite long as it allows users to update their information. Is there a part in particular you want to see? I have made an edit on the original post and uploaded what the invoice should (used to) look like. Automatically email invoice when user purchases online was ticked. I unticked this and tested again. 2 emails are still sent, both emails do not have any pdf invoices attached.